# multiple definitions of function in .cpp file

Tags: c++, function, include, declaration

## Edit:

Sigh, I feel like an idiot. I never had c++ file inclusion properly explained to me until months after I asked his question. Please refrain from commenting on exactly how flawed my setup was, I know perfectly well.

I have a multiple-file project containing many .h and .cpp files. One in particular, io_util.h, produces a bizarre series of errors. For the .h, which contains function declarations but no implementations, compiles perfectly, but in the .cpp, where the function bodies are, every function creates the following error:

```
   Multiple markers at this line
- first defined here
- multiple definition of 
 `<namespace>::<function name>(<args>)'
```

The file "io_util.cpp" is included only once in the project, CollectionBase.h. "io_util.h" is only included by "io_util.cpp"

Here are the two files:

.h:

```
/*
 * io_util.h
 */

#ifndef IO_UTIL_H_
#define IO_UTIL_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

#define IO_DEBUG(a) cout << #a << '=' << a << '\n'

#define CASE_SEP 32
#define NUM_CHAR_SEP 48

namespace std
{
    void getVar(int&, int);
    
    void getVar(double&, double);
    
    void getVar(unsigned&, unsigned);
    
    int get_num_digits(int);
    
    int get_digit(int, const int, const int);
    
    string value_of(int);
}

#endif /* IO_UTIL_H_ */
```

.cpp:

```
/*
 * io_util.cpp
 */
#ifndef IO_H_
#define IO_H_

#include "io_util.h"

namespace std
{

void getVar(int& i, int forbidden = NAN)
{
    string str;

    while(true)
    {
        getline(cin,str);

        if(str.find_first_not_of("-0123456789") != string::npos || !(stringstream(str) >> i))
        {
            cout << "invalid input.\n\n";
        }
        else if(i == forbidden)
        {
            cout << "illegal value.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void getVar(double& d, double forbidden = NAN)
{
    string str;

    while(true)
    {
        getline(cin,str);

        if(str.find_first_not_of("-.0123456789eE") != string::npos || !(stringstream(str) >> d))
        {
            cout << "invalid input.\n\n";
        }
        else if(d == forbidden)
        {
            cout << "illegal value.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void getVar(unsigned & u, unsigned forbidden = NAN)
{
    string str;

    while(true)
    {
        getline(cin,str);

        if(str.find_first_not_of("0123456789") != string::npos || !(stringstream(str) >> u))
        {
            cout << "invalid input.\n\n";
        }
        else if(u == forbidden)
        {
            cout << "illegal value.\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int get_num_digits(int i)
{
    if(i < 0)
    {
        i = -i;
    }

    int result = 1;

    while(i > 10)
    {
        i /= 10;
        result++;
    }

    return result;
}

int get_digit(int i, const int num_digits, const int dig)
{
    if(num_digits < dig)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    const int dig_p10 = pow(10.0,num_digits - dig);

    i -= dig_p10 * round(i/dig_p10);

    if (dig < num_digits - 1)
    {
        i = round(i/int(pow(10.0,num_digits - dig - 1)));
    }

    return i;
}

string value_of(int i)
{
    string str;

    if (i < 0)
    {
        str += "-";
        i = -i;
    }

    const int num_dig = get_num_digits(i);

    for(int n = 0; n < num_dig; n++)
    {
        str += char(get_digit(i, num_dig, n) + NUM_CHAR_SEP);
    }

    return str;
}

}

#endif /*IO_H_*/
```

I have looked through many questions on this site regarding similar phenomena but none of them have helped.

Comment: Can I ask what the fencepost for IO_H is doing in your cpp file? Also, your .cpp file has default values in the getVar() parameter lists. Those don't belong there. they belong in the .h file (or really need to brush up on my standards docs). The latter is likely the source of your error, btw.

Comment: "The file "io_util.cpp" is included only once in the project, CollectionBase.h. "io_util.h" is only included by "io_util.cpp"
Shouldn't the io_util.h be included in CollectionBase.h and not io_util.cpp?

Comment: If you `#include` a .cpp file from a .h file, that would explain everything.

Comment: My first guess is that you have a `#include "io_util.cpp"` line in some OTHER file not shown here. To paraphrase Winston Churchill, "never, never, never, never `#include` .cpp files."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, io_util.cpp should be in the *source* file list of code files to be compiled. Everywhere in your project that needs the functionality contained therein should be including io_util.h, including CollectionBase.h. Do **not** #include .cpp files in **anything** (i.e. no #include "io_util.cpp" allowed).

Second, your io_util.h header declares functions within the std namespace (which is also a no-no) called getVar(). The default parameter values for the trailing parameters belong *there*; **not** in the io_util.cpp file.

Fixing both of those should get you substantially further down the road.

Comment: So let me see if I get this straight: include the .cpp at the bottom of the .h, and then include the .h in all of my other files?

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Um no. How many .cpp files are in your program ? At this point I'm guessing two.

Comment: a few more than that, for a few class, but they shouldn't affect this. I have a main.cpp where the program starts and io_util.cpp.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Compile each .cpp file *separately*. **Never** include a .cpp file using a #include statement in a source file. Do you know how to compile multiple .cpp files into a single final executable?

Comment: Apparently not. I was always taught that there was no practical difference between .cpp and .h files, and that the different extensions were used only because of convention. Obviously this appears to not be the case.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart that is seriously not the case. a .cpp is what gets compiled. A .h is an "interface" specification (ok, a little more complex but you get the idea). A .h is there to tell .cpp files what is available in other .cpp files that have not yet been compiled.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Yes, I realized a long time ago (this post is kind of embarassing now actually... I was actually thinking of adding that comment myself to complete the thread.